# Django environment/setup issue: AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'USE_REDIS'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to django and docker setup environment.

I have an existing django project that I need to deploy on my local server. I am configuring my python environment on Windows for Linux Ubuntu 18.04 TLS.
I am able to do my setup with pipenv install. Following django packages got installed:

```
Django==3.0.5
django-cors-headers==3.2.1
django-debug-toolbar==2.2
django-environ==0.4.5
django-filter==2.2.0
django-polymorphic==2.1.2
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

but when I run django-admin --version, I get error:

> AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'USE_REDIS'

Full stack-trace is as given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_code/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_code/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_code/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_code/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_code/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_code/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/c/Users/test/git_repos/lab/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    from catalystlab.data.models.entity import Tag, Type, Entity, update_types
  File "//mnt/c/Users/test/git_repos/lab/data/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    DATA_CACHE = caches['default' if settings.USE_REDIS else 'fallback']
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/project_code/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 77, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'USE_REDIS'
```

I would like to know if this attribute has to be in django settings by default or I need to update django settings with additional details.

Comment: you need to add it as an additional variable. i think this is because you are using a package that requires it

Comment: Yes, in my code, I am using like:

DATA_CACHE = caches['default' if settings.USE_REDIS else 'fallback']

but what should be the value of variable if I need to add it in settings.

Comment: i believe you can set it to `False` unless you really need to use it

Comment: I have set it to False and installed Redis too.

Now I am getting error:

"Could not find config for '%s' in settings.CACHES" % alias
django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find config for 'fallback' in settings.CACHES

Comment: try setting it to True. also you need to set the fallback cache just in case

Answer (score 1):

You should see Django settings.

The value should be a bool, so either 1 or 0.

upgrade Redis and try...

> pip upgrade Redis

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, you need to set it on your Django settings. It looks like the value should be a bool, so either `True` or `False`.

If it's an existing project, it's likely it's supposed to work with the code as is, so you would need some other configuration, that ultimately leads to the correct settings configuration. I'm thinking it can be as environment variable, or your settings checks for a redis installation. It can be as indicated from documentation from dependency, or per the project itself.
It might be that you also need to... install Redis, if you haven't already. You mentioned Windows for Linux Ubuntu 18.04, so assuming you refer to the new-ish windows-supported Ubuntu shell, I think you need to install it there too, as it cannot access a potential Windows installation either.
Or it can be an issue with the docker configuration not including the environnment variables/stack necessary. I don't understand the deal with running docker in a VM shell.

Comment: I have set it to False and installed Redis too. Now I am getting error: "Could not find config for '%s' in settings.CACHES" % alias django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find config for 'fallback' in settings.CACHES.

a silly question, where can I check docker configuration?

Comment: for my environment as you understand, where should I install docker tools, on Ubuntu or on my base Windows machine?

Comment: If i understand your setup, you are running windows as main OS, which is running the Ubuntu VM, which is running Docker and pipenv. As the application is running inside the Ubuntu shell, Windows is out of the picture and should be irrelevant. I'm not so familiar with docker yet, but the whole point of docker to have a standardized environnment that includes such config, so I think the docker conf should be where to specify the environnment variables.